# Adding type class to the function defenition doesn't help in Haskell

Tags: haskell, enums, typeclass

In the line

```
eval :: (Enum Instruction) => [Instruction] -> [Value] -> [Value]
eval inst mem = evalSecond (evalStep ((fromList Halt inst), (fromList 0 mem), (0,0,0,0), (ZeroFlag, EvenFlag)))
```

where fromList is

```
fromList ::(Enum a) => a -> [a] -> Tape a
fromList a xs = (Tape 0 inf (xs ++ inf))
    where inf = [a, a..]
```

I'm getting this error when calling the function eval:

```
    • No instance for (Enum Instruction) arising from a use of ‘eval’
    • In the expression: eval [Test M, Halt] [32, 123, 0]
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = eval [Test M, Halt] [32, 123, 0]
```

Can someone explain me please?

I can't understand why it asks for Enum Instruction when it is already there

Comment: Where is your implementation of `Enum` for `Instruction`? You either have to define one or `deriving Enum` on the definiton of `Instruction`

Comment: Adding the constraint to the function means `a` must have a `Enum` instance; it doesn't *provide* an `Enum` instance for `a`.

Answer (score 1):

In `eval` you are requiring that the `Instruction` type is an instance of the `Enum` type class, but no such instance definition can be found. Thus, `eval` cannot be called.

In order to make `Instruction` an instance of `Enum`, you have to provide definitions for `toEnum :: Int -> Instruction` and `fromEnum :: Instruction -> Int`:

```
instance Enum Instruction where
  toEnum   _ = _     -- Replace with your actual code
  fromEnum _ = _
```

Of course, you want `toEnum . fromEnum` to be equal to `id` (but this is not necessarily true for `fromEnum . toEnum`, as that function might not be total.)

If your data type is actually a sum of nullary constructors, you can make Haskell write those functions for you by either writing

```
deriving Enum
```

directly after the data type definition or by writing

```
deriving instance Enum Instruction
```

somewhere else. For other data types, there might be different mechanisms.